# MySQL в Opencart импорт

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Проблема следующая. Есть скрипт, который пачками по 1000 товаров импортит товар в магазин на Opencart 2.3. Когда опенкарт начинает обрабатывать запрос бд, то весь опенкарт ложится, ибо для любой страницы ему нужен запрос к базе данных, а она не отвечает ввиду обработки запроса. Какой вариант можно придумать, кроме как уйти в запросы по одному товару.

Comment: Заменить mysql на mariadb (многопоточность)? Перепроверить и при возможности понизить transaction isolation level (снижает количество блокировок во время операций вставки/обновления)? Перепроверить возможность снижения количества foreign keys в таблицах, куда скрипт добавляет данные (снижает время и количество блокировок связанных таблиц и повышает "отзывчивость" базы)? Перейти в скрипте на подготовленные запросы и все-таки вгонять данные по 1 позиции за раз, но используя подготовленный запрос (снижает время выполнения запроса)? **Из предоставленных исходных данных лично я больше не выжму.**

Comment: Да, добавить sleep(1) после sql-запроса вставки данных в скрипте импорта. Хоть "рывками", но запросы пробиваться будут.